# django runserver, skiping/caching? requests when multiple executed at the same time

Tags: django, python-3.x, multithreading

When running **django-admin runserver** and executing multiple **PATCH** requests at the same time, I see logs for all but only one is executed when I debug.

The problem disappeared when using **django-admin runserver --nothreading**.

I am using Pycharm debugger, maybe because runserver is by default using **multithreading**, so when 2 requests come at the same time a second thread is created which is not seen/debugged by Pycharm. So thats why I cannot debug it but I see logs.

But the second thing is that only one request is successful with PATCH update, I know django-admin runserver is not aim for production but is there any **data race condition** ? I have tried to use **django.db.transaction.atomic** but it didn't make any change ?

**My initial conclusion is that runserver is not thread save if we consider database updates, so if testing multiple updating requests --nothreading flag should be used.**

I would appreciate any help/explanation here.

Best,
Igor

P.S. I haven;t any code as I think it doesn't help here in any way:

Comment: Hi @Alasdair, You are right --nothreading is only hiding the problem I have already modified my code to use select_for_update, thanks. If You want please modify Your comment to answer, You solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transaction.atomic()` ensures that either all the queries in a block are committed to the database or none do. It doesn't stop different threads/processes modifying the same rows at the same time. To do that you should look into locking or [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update).

When you deploy Django using something like `gunicorn` or `mod_wsgi`, there will normally be multiple workers/threads. Therefore if you use `--nothreading` in development, you are hiding issues that may appear in production.